# Update Django model field when actions taking place in another model

Tags: python, django, model, signals

I want to make changes in a model instance A, when a second model instance B
is saved,updated or deleted.
All models are in the same Django app.
What would be the optimal way to do it?

1. Should I use signals?
2. Override default methods[save, update,delete]?
3. Something else?

Django documentation warns:

> Where possible you should opt for directly calling the handling code, rather than dispatching via a signal.

Can somebody elaborate on that statement?

Answer (score 0):

The performance impact of your signal handlers depends of course on their functionality. But you should be aware of the fact that they are executed synchronously when the signal is fired, so if there's a lot of action going on in the handlers (for example a lot of database calls) the execution will be delayed.

Comment: I was aware of that, I forgot to mention that the models are connected via Foreign Key.
In the second case i was thinking of calling the object instance in the methods and update the values that i want . How would you have done it?